# is there such a thing as a 3-boundary or "hypersurface" in $\mathbb{R}^3$? RE:de Rham chain complexes.

Tags: differential-topology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

This set of lecture notes asserts that there is such a thing as a hypersurface, or 3-boundary in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  To me a boundary is a set of limit points of a set for which every open ball centered on that limit point contains both an element of theset, and an element of the complement of that set.

See page 10. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.4991.pdf

If there IS such a thing as a 3-boundary in $\mathbb{R}^3$, what would be an example?  What would the bounded set be?

Comment: It doesn't say that it's a thing in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: They're just plain wrong. A hypersurface in $\Bbb R^3$ is, indeed, a surface.

Comment: @DonThousand: That whole paragraph is specifically about $\Bbb R^3$, allegedly.

Comment: @TedShifrin I can't imagine that was intentional.

Comment: No, nonsense usually isn't :)